# How would I split a string a string into a list of words, punctuation and spaces? (taking apostrophes into account)

Tags: regex, dart

How do I split a string into words, punctuation and spaces using regex?

Example:

- Input String: `"One day you're going to 'solve' this problem"`
- Output List: `["One", " ","day"," ","you're"," ","going"," ","to"," ","'","solve","'","  ","this","problem"]`

I have looked at a whole list of answers to this question however they all have some deficiency:

- Not matching words with an apostrophe e.g. `you're`
- Matching words with an apostrophe but also words that are followed by an apostrophe e.g. `'This is a cat'`
- Not being a generalized solution (creating a regex that works with the specific punctuation in the example string but not working with all punctuation).

Examples I have tried that have almost worked but not quite:

- `RegExp(r"\w+|[^\w\s]+| ").allMatches(string)`
- `RegExp(r"[\w']+|[.,!?; ]").allMatches(string)`
- `string.split(RegExp(r"(?=[.\s]|\b)"))`

Comment: For a problem like this, I really, really recommend sitting down and *specifying*, in sometimes painful detail, what it is you want to match. What is a "word" to you? Obviously you want to include apostrophes like in "ain't". Do you want dashes like in "user-defined"? What else might you want? What about digits? Is "42" a word? You're treating it as one by using `\w`, but do you then want to accept fractional numbers too, like "0.5"? Leading signs like "-2.5"? What punctuation do you want to match? Common ones like `.,:` or also `;`, mdash, ndash, or quotes? Smart quotes? *Which* whitespace?

Comment: For my specific use case, all these edge cases aren't critical, however it is a good point in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build on something like this:

```
(
   (?<word>\w+(?:'\w+)*) |
   (?<ws>\s+) |
   (?<punc>[?:;.,'"()])
)
```

https://regex101.com/r/jJbFQd/1

Comment: As a Dart RegExp, that would be `RegExp(r"((?<word>\w+(?:'\w+)*)|(?<ws>\s+)|(?<punc>[?:;.,'"()]))")`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
/[!?;:,. '"]|\w+(?:'\w+)*/gm
```

It will first try to match one of these in brackets and then try to match either of:

- Any word characters followed by `'` followed by any words characters.
- Any word characters

The pattern above can be checked working. Any missing cases, feel free to reach out.

https://regex101.com/r/iKk5Gc/1